Neo4j 5.23 migration from Community Edition to Enterprise
I have a startup license for Neo4j Enterprise Edition and would like to migrate to it from my current Neo4j 5.23.0 Community Edition.
The following steps are described in the documentation for this:
https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/version-5/
Stop the running Neo4j 5 Community Edition server:

neo4j stop

Backup the system and neo4j databases using the neo4j-admin database dump command:

neo4j-admin database dump neo4j

neo4j-admin database dump system

By default, dumps are located to data/dumps/. Alternatively, the location can be defined via the conf/neo4j.conf setting server.directories.dumps.root.

Load the system and neo4j databases into the Neo4j 5 Enterprise Edition server using neo4j-admin database load:

neo4j-admin database load neo4j --from-path=<path-to-community-neo4j-dump>

neo4j-admin database load system --from-path=<path-to-community-system-dump>

Navigate to the Neo4j 5 Enterprise Edition server and start it:

neo4j start

I have a few questions:

To get the most out of using Neo4j Enterprise Edition, I would like my migrated database to use the Block Store Format. Do I need to take any additional steps during the migration, and when exactly should I do this to achieve it?

I have my license number — do I need to provide it somewhere during the installation of Neo4j Enterprise Edition?




Block formatting became the default store format for Enterprise Edition in 5.22. So, you do not need to do anything special to enable block formatting for EE in 5.23.

If you have a commercial Enterprise Edition (EE) license, you can ask neo4j support how to use the license (especially if you want to use EE past the initial trial period). There are a variety of ways to install the EE, and unfortunately the current documentation rarely mentions how to use a license file. However, the default locations for neo4j license files is documented here.



I'm not sure about block format migration, but I can answer the questions about the installation process:

It depends on how you installed Neo4j to begin with. If you used a deb or rpm installer then you will need to backup then uninstall neo4j community before you can install enterprise edition. If you installed from tar.gz it should be ok.
No you don't need it during installation.


Thank you for your response, but I am also interested in information about block format migration, as this is one of the main reasons why I want to proceed with this migration.
